# XAMPP all to undefined function pg_connect()

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, xampp

I've installed XAMPP in Manjaro. I'm struggling to solve this issue.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()
```

I've read some posts and I've also tried to follow these steps

```
Open php.ini
Find ;extension=php_pgsql.dll and remove the semicolon at the beginning
Find ;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll and remove the semicolon at the beginning
Save the file
Restart apache (kudos @Inventillect)
```

But it didn't work for me.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using linux.

Edit file php.ini, find `;extension="pgsql.so"` and remove the semicolon at the beginning.

Please pay attention that "pgsql.so" is different with "php_pgsql.dll"